# React onClick not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am currently building my first, very basic react app. There is a button that triggers an API call using onClick. However, react just doesn't seem to be rendering the onclick to the DOM.

Within index.js I have, among other, the following content:

```
<NumberSelect
    label={"Can I get your number?"}
    id_input1={"number-input"}
    placeholder={42}
    onClickEvent={RequestFact}
    cta={"Get Fact"}
    />
```

This is my NumberSelect.js:

```
import Button from "./Button.js";
import InputNumber from "./InputNumber.js";

import "./NumberSelect.css";

const NumberSelect = (props) => {
    return (
        <form id="number-select">
            <label htmlFor={props.id_input1}>{props.label}</label>
            <InputNumber
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                id_input1={props.id_input1}
            />
            <Button
                cta={props.cta}
                class={"btn mt-10"}
                href={props.href}
                onClickEvent={props.onClickEvent}
            />
        </form>
    );
};

export default NumberSelect;
```

And this is the entire Button.js

```
import "./Button.css";

const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <a
            id={props.id}
            className={props.class}
            href={props.href}
            onClick={props.onClickEvent}
        >
            {props.cta}
        </a>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

What I would *expect* the HTML to look like is this (note:  is defined in a separate Component):

```
<form id="number-select">
    <label for="number-input">Can I get your number?</label
    ><input
        type="text"
        inputmode="numeric"
        pattern="[0-9]*"
        id="number-input"
        placeholder="42"
        spellcheck="false"
        data-ms-editor="true"
    /><a class="btn mt-10" onclick="RequestFact()">Get Fact</a>
</form>
```

But this is what the HTML actually looks like:

```
<form id="number-select">
    <label for="number-input">Can I get your number?</label
    ><input
        type="text"
        inputmode="numeric"
        pattern="[0-9]*"
        id="number-input"
        placeholder="42"
        spellcheck="false"
        data-ms-editor="true"
    /><a class="btn mt-10">Get Fact</a>
</form>
```

Almost everything is the same, only the `onclick="RequestFact()` is missing.

Can anybody help me out? Do you need any other info?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I tried to simplify the code a bit and not post everything here. But it seems I took away too much and it became unclear. Sorry for that. Above some additional code.

Info regarding the additional questions:

- RequestFact ist located in index.js
- Thanks for the tip regarding `{` for strings - will implement

Comment: Event listeners don't "render". They are attached through javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by `onClick` not rendering to the DOM ? and what is `RequestFact` ? `RequestFact` is not defined inside your component ?

Comment: as @tkausl says this is nothing to be worried about - `onclick` etc in React do not correspond to actual HTML attributes of that name. But the click functionality will still work, assuming of course the rest of your code is correct. The question is: does the button do what you expect when you click on it? If so, there's no problem, if not then please edit your question to give more details.

Comment: PS when giving string values to attributes/props you do not need the {...}. `id="test-id"` would work fine, similarly for `className`

Comment: where is your "RequestFact" function?

Comment: Just edited my question to accomodate your remarks - thanks!

Comment: @RobinZigmond, interesting - I just replaced my  `onClick={props.onClickEvent}` with this `onClick={console.log("test1234")}`

For some reason, this fires exactly 5 times right when the page is loaded (I have 5 buttons on the page), but clicking the buttons has no effect. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @loocd To help illustrate what the above comments are saying - open up the console on this page, paste in and run the following code, and inspect the button that it renders. Notice there are no attributes, yet the click still executes a function. `const el = document.createElement('button');
el.innerHTML = 'Test';
el.addEventListener('click', () => alert('test'));
const p = document.getElementById('comments-69093257');
p.append(el);`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the example @BrianThompson! But if I do it like this instead (everything else left exactly as above): 
`<NumberSelect
    label={"Can I get your number?"}
    id_input1={"number-input"}
    placeholder={42}
    onClickEvent={console.log("testsdfsdf")}
    cta={"Get Fact"}
    />`

Why does the console.log fire right when the page loads but never when I click the button?

Comment: Because plain JS/HTML attributes do not get assigned the same way as JSX props. Here you are instructing `NumberSelect` that the value of `onClickEvent` should be the **result** of the function call `console.log()`. The return of `console.log` is `undefined` so you're not actually passing it anything, but instead logging the string *each render*.

Comment: to expand on what @BrianThompson correctly said, if you want to log that string on each button click, you would instead do `onClick={() => console.log("test1234")}` (or put that in a separate function and then do, if the function was called `myFunction`, `onClick={myFunction}`)

Comment: Allright, this is all starting to make sense - thanks! 

So just to be sure - my inital code where I pass the prop with `onClickEvent={RequestFact}` was actually correct, but potentially I need to look over RequestFact again?

Or would it need to be something like `onClickEvent={() => RequestFact}`?